# CSS class priority

Tags: css

I *think* I understand class specificity rules. I would like to have a class or id called themecolor that I can put on any element that I want to take on that color. Sometimes it's a background, other times it's the color of an icon.

```
.themecolor {
  color: rgb(47, 86, 111);
}
```

I am using it with Bootstrap so for example I have this:

```
<div class="themecolor navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
```

and this:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-#{icon} themecolor" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="#{tooltip}"></span>)
```

It doesn't work because there are more specific rules in each of those cases which defeat my color. However I'd rather avoid having the theme color rule be dependent on where it's used.

By the way I tried `!important` and that didn't do it either.

Comment: Can you provide a working sample?

Comment: We can't know the specificity of the other selectors if you don't post them.

Comment: This sounds more like you want a *variable* than a class. It can't be both the background AND the color...the text would be invisible.

Comment: I didn't think variables were a css feature?

Comment: oriol and dekel : the other selectors come out of the bowels of bootstrap and are quite specific. I will try and dig them up.

Comment: I messed up: @Paulie_D correctly reminded me that I was using "color" on a navbar, where I meant background color. I am still curious about my question though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS *is* all about context.

The style an element receives depends on:

1. Specificity
2. Position in the cascade

**Specificity**

- `p {}` is less specific than
- `p.introduction {}` which is less specific than
- `article p.introduction {}` which is less specific than
- `article#profile p.introduction {}` etc.

**Cascade**

For situations where specificity is equivalent...

- In `article p {color: green;} body p {color: red;}` the paragraph text will be `red`.
- But in `body p {color: red;} article p {color: green;}` the paragraph text will be `green`.

---

So, although you write:

> I would like to have a class [...] called `.themecolor` that I can put on
>   any element that I want to take on that `background-color`.

as you will have seen, using:

```
.themecolor {
background-color: rgb(47, 86, 111);
}
```

will often not work - because, your `.themecolor` declaration might easily (albeit accidentally) get overridden by a more specific selector elsewhere in your stylesheet, or by a selector of equivalent specificity further down the cascade.

Better then, to group selectors together, using your `.themecolor` as a quasi-variable:

```
.THEMECOLOR,
.navbar.themecolor,
.glyphicon.themecolor {
background-color: rgb(47, 86, 111);
}
```

You will then be able to add as many new elements to this list as you wish, always stating the main Bootstrap class of the element immediately followed by .themecolor:

```
.THEMECOLOR,
.class1.themecolor,
.class2.themecolor,
.class3.themecolor,
.class4.themecolor,
.class5.themecolor,
.class6.themecolor {
background-color: rgb(47, 86, 111);
}
```

**N.B.** The syntax `.class1.themecolor` means:

> When an element has `.class1` ***and*** it has `.themecolor`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I learned some subtleties! So would this have worked:

`.THEMECOLOR,
.navbar.themecolor,
.glyphicon.themecolor {
background-color: rgb(47, 86, 111);
}` for me? Also what's the purpose of the all caps THEMECOLOR?

Comment: .THEMECOLOR, doesn't do anything -  it's just a comment designed to jump out at you so you can quickly find the `.themecolor` part of your stylesheet.

Comment: And yes, that's it: `.navbar.themecolor, .glyphicon.themecolor, .something-else.themecolor, .another-thing.themecolor, .yet-another-thing.themecolor { background-color: rgb(47, 86, 111); }` will absolutely work.

Answer (score 0):

I messed up: @Paulie_D correctly reminded me that I was using "color" on a navbar, where I meant background color.

I am still curious about my question though